# How to get the last parent from table for the following scenario in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tree, sql-server-2000

I have the following scenario of a tree in SQL Server 2000.

There is database with two tables, figuratively speaking

`Table1` (Row_Id *int*, Id *char(9)*, etc.)

*AND*

`Table2` (Row_Id *int*, Parent_Id *char(9)*, Parent_Parent_Id *char(9)*, etc).

`Parent_Id` in `Table2` refers to `Id` in `Table1`.

`Parent_Parent_Id` in `Table2` refers to `Id` in `Table1` too (thus child can have more than one parent).

For example, let's consider the tables with some data:

**Table1**

```
Row_Id  Id 
  1     a  
  2     b  
  3     c  
  4     d  
  5     e  
  6    ...
```

**Table2**

```
Row_Id  Parent_Id  Parent_Parent_Id
  1        a               b
  2        b               с   
  3        c               d
  4        d               e   
  5       ...             ...
```

This scenario with data shows that element with `Id` 'a' from `Table1` has no more parents and that the last parent of the element with `Id` 'a' is 'e'.

The other words I would like to write stored procedure with input parameter `inId` (it is any `Id` from `Table1`) and as result I would like to get the **last parent who has no more parents**.

Now I do this via loop with

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Parent_Id 
WHERE Table1.Id = inId
```

until I get `NULL` in the right.

How do you think is there any better way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: **last Parent, who has no more Childs** I think it should be **last Parent, who has no more Parents**. In your example, `e` is last parent which has no more parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server versions after 2000 there are several ways to to this efficiently. In SQL 2000 however, you are stuc resolving this manually. There are two options:

- a recursive function or procedure
- a loop

If the loop is written correctly, it is most likely going to be the faster of the two. Just make sure you have appropriate indexes on the tables.

You also don't need to join to table1. just do something like  `SELECT @newParent = Parent_Parent_Id FORM dbo.Table2 WHERE Parent_Id = @currentParent;` in the loop and stop if no new parent is found.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the loop, that have decided my problem. Thank you.

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

DECLARE @currentParent char(9),
        @newParent char(9)

SELECT @currentParent = 'a',
       @newParent = @currentParent

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @newParent = Parent_Parent_Id 
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE Parent_Id = @currentParent;

    IF (@newParent = @currentParent) 
        BEGIN
            PRINT @newParent;
            BREAK;
        END;

    SELECT @currentParent = @newParent;
END
```